# Run time while loop condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures

```
def selection_sort(a):
    for i in range(0, len(a) - 1):
        minIndex = i
        for j in range(i + 1, len(a)):
            if a[j] < a[minIndex]:
                minIndex = j
            if minIndex != i:
                a[i], a[minIndex] = a[minIndex], a[i]

def selection_sort_runs():
    run_time_list = []
    n = 1
    while [having trouble thinking of loop condition here]
        start_time = time.time()
        rand = [random.randint(0, 100) for x in range(1, 10001*n)]
        selection_sort(rand)
        end_time = time.time()
        run_time = end_time - start_time
        run_time_list.append(run_time)
        if run_time < 60:
            n += 1
```

I want to continue the loop until run_time is greater than 60, but I can't think of a condition that will allow me to do so and increment n by one because run_time is a product that is contained inside of the loop, any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Two of the possible options you have would be to use a `break` statement

```
    while True:
        start_time = time.time()
        rand = [random.randint(0, 100) for x in range(1, 10001*n)]
        selection_sort(rand)
        end_time = time.time()
        run_time = end_time - start_time
        run_time_list.append(run_time)
        if run_time < 60:
            n += 1
        else:
            break
```

Or you could refactor the code so the `run_time` variable is initialized outside the loop.

```
run_time = -1        
while run_time < 60:
        start_time = time.time()
        rand = [random.randint(0, 100) for x in range(1, 10001*n)]
        selection_sort(rand)
        end_time = time.time()
        run_time = end_time - start_time
        run_time_list.append(run_time)
        if run_time < 60:
            n += 1
```

Comment: @busybear Not necessarily. You would end up over counting by 1 without the if statement since the last iteration before the break would be over 60. You could decrement it by 1 after the end of the loop to get around that though.

Comment: True. I didn't read what each variable was doing carefully enough and assumed some things :)